# Role Based Security in the Administrators windows group

Tags: c#, .net, security

I'm trying to understand role based security and I have the following method:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Administrators")]
static void Test()
{
    //administratos only can call this code
}
```

What I wanna do is that only users that are members of the Windows Administrators group can call this code, however, if I do the following, it works:

```
GenericIdentity genericIdentity = new GenericIdentity("test", "test");
GenericPrincipal genericPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(genericIdentity, new string[] { "Administrators" });
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(genericPrincipal);

Test();
```

So, how can I make it work only if the user is in the Administrators windows group?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the PrincipalPolicy? You need that to check roles against Windows groups.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal)
```

Comment: where should I add this line of code? inside my protected method Test?

Comment: You'd add it somewhere in your application startup code. You would want to have the policy set before you try to demand the security.